# Вопрос по preg_match_all

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

```
preg_match_all ('|<div class="offer">(.+)</div>|isU', $page, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

У меня выводится все до первого закрытого дива `</div>`

А как сделать так, чтобы выводилось все до четвертого закрытого дива?

Буду очень благодарен за подсказку

Comment: а чем вас парсер не устраивает? и что значит - до 4-го? только дивы или все подряд от 1-го до 4-го?

Comment: После <div class="offer"> есть много других поддивов, мне нужно добраться до последнего </div>, чтобы спарсить весь блок <div class="offer">. А у меня сейчас парсинг находит первый </div> и останавливается

Comment: приведите тестовый фрагмент html в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Собственно вот решение )

```
|<div class="offer">(.+?)</div>.+?</div>.+?</div>.+?</div>|isU
```